# How to run jest tests in Nest js?

Tags: testing, jestjs, nestjs

I am currently writing tests for the services I wrote by I keep running into an error when trying to run test suite with the command `npm run test`. I researched on the moduleNameWrapper property for test configuration with jest but I keep getting the error

```bash
 FAIL  src/domain/api/v1/authentication/authentication.service.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Configuration error:

    Could not locate module @/infra/gateways/database/prisma/prisma.service mapped as:
    /home/daniel/Workspace/Projects/project1/src/$1.

    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/^@\/(.*)$/": "/home/daniel/Workspace/Projects/project1/src/$1"
      },
      "resolver": undefined
    }

      17 |   SiteHelpers,
      18 | } from '@/common/helpers/app.helpers';
    > 19 | import { PrismaService } from '@/infra/gateways/database/prisma/prisma.service';
         | ^
      20 | import { AppConfig } from '@/lib/config/config.provider';
      21 | import {
      22 |   HubInviteeQueryDto,

      at createNoMappedModuleFoundError (../node_modules/.pnpm/jest-resolve@29.7.0/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:759:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (domain/api/v1/authentication/authentication.service.ts:19:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (domain/api/v1/authentication/authentication.service.spec.ts:1:1)
```

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@/domain/*": ["./src/domain/*"],
      "@/infra/*": ["./src/infrastructure/*"],
      "@/lib/*": ["./src/lib/*"],
      "@/utils/*": ["./src/utils/*"],
      "@/common/*": ["./src/common/*"]
    },
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

Again with my jest configuration in my package.json

```js
"jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1"
    },
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
```

I don't really know what I am doing wrong here

I tried changing the moduleNameWrapper property for the test configuration for jest with what I saw in some closed GitHub issues still got the same error. I am thinking the problem stems from my path aliases in my tsconfig.json but I am not to sure.